# HTML table expands past 100% height on window re-size

Tags: html, css, html-table, twitch

So I have a table with some twitch.tv widgets in it. I want the table to stay fixed at 100% width & height in the viewport so the elements inside resize to fit whatever window size the user has. I want there to be no scrolling.

The problem is that when the user adjusts the window size the height ends up pushing past 100% and not scaling back down to fit (forcing them to f5 or scroll). What is going on? How do I fix this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<html style="height: 99%;">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="height: 99%;">

<table width="100%" style="height: 99%;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" width="350"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=twitchraidstwitch&amp;popout_chat=true" height="99%" width="350"></iframe></td>
      <td><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="99%" width="100%" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=internationalspacepimps" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=twitchraidstwitch&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object></td>
      <td rowspan="2" width="350"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=monstercat&amp;popout_chat=true" height="99%" width="350"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="99%" width="100%" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=internationalspacepimps" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=twitchraidstwitch&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, clarify the problem. What is expected result? And what you actually get?

Comment: When resizing the window the table does not re-size to fit the page vertically. A scrollbar appears and the content extends downward off the fold. I want my table to be the size of the viewport always.